# Meaning of "through all right"

Tags: meaning, idioms

What does the phrase *through all right* mean?

> He'll see me *through all right*

Comment: Could you please give some more context? Like where did someone say it, and what was happening? Also, have you done some research on your own?

Comment: [Martin Eden](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Martin_Eden/Chapter_I) first paragraph, last sentence.

Comment: Yes. For me, it means "He will look after me, and it will be ok."

Comment: @Alder, I think you have it.  More specifically though, It's the evening's activities that the boy is anxious about and through which he is now confident *the one* will help him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set phrase here is *see me through* rather than *through all right*.

ODO's entry for [see *someone* through](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/see?q=see%20you%20through#see__87) reads:

> support a person for the duration of a difficult time.